# HTML SVG Positioning?

Tags: html, css, svg

so i have a little problem with a svg, this svg is align on left side, but i want make it to the right side, I've tried using x and y but its not working, please help me

```html
<svg width="498" height="99" fill="none"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M0 36C0 2.863 26.8629-24 60-24
  h438V99H60C26.8629 99 0 72.1371 0 39v-3Z" fill="#2D2D2D"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an outer div like this:

```
<div class='outer-div' > 
    <!-- SVG Element -->
    <svg></svg>
</div>
```

And in the CSS file:

```
.outer-div{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of options depending on the context. Here I present:

1. CSS float
2. CSS text-align
3. CSS position
4. CSS flexbox
5. and SVG viewBox

### CSS float

A bit old-school I guess. It works, but the downside is that the SVG takes up 0 px height.

```css
svg {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<svg width="498" height="99" fill="none"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M0 36C0 2.863 26.8629-24 60-24
  h438V99H60C26.8629 99 0 72.1371 0 39v-3Z" fill="#2D2D2D"/>
</svg>
```

### CSS text-align

The SVG is displayed as an inline element, so it behaves like a text.

```css
.parent {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <svg width="498" height="99" fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 36C0 2.863 26.8629-24 60-24
    h438V99H60C26.8629 99 0 72.1371 0 39v-3Z" fill="#2D2D2D"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

## CSS position

If the parent is positioned relative (or absolute) and the SVG is positioned absolute the property right can be used for aligning the SVG.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <svg width="498" height="99" fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 36C0 2.863 26.8629-24 60-24
    h438V99H60C26.8629 99 0 72.1371 0 39v-3Z" fill="#2D2D2D"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

### CSS flexbox

The more modern version of the above examples.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <svg width="498" height="99" fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 36C0 2.863 26.8629-24 60-24
    h438V99H60C26.8629 99 0 72.1371 0 39v-3Z" fill="#2D2D2D"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

### SVG vieBox

And lastly, by using the viewBox attribute instead of the width and the height attributes, the `<path>` can be positioned in the right side of the SVG itself (the `transform` attribute). The SVG will take up 100 % of the width at all times and the `<path>` will therefore also "float" to the right. This will make the SVG scale up and down depending on the width available.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 700 99" fill="none"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path transform="translate(262 0)" d="M0 36C0 2.863 26.8629-24 60-24
  h438V99H60C26.8629 99 0 72.1371 0 39v-3Z" fill="#2D2D2D"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this?

```html
<svg width="498" height="99" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M0 36C0 2.863 26.8629-24 60-24h438V99H60C26.8629 99 0 72.1371 0 39v-3Z" fill="#2D2D2D" transform="scale (-1, 1)" transform-origin="center" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).